# Comparing array to database table, if any matches are found, get the img url and insert into PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, image

so basicaly my conundrum is folowing:

I have a database like this:

```
Word   |   imgUrl   |   imgSize
volvo  | C:\Users\..|     15
```

And I have an array like this:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

I need PHP to compare what in the array with whats in the database column **Word** , then retrieve a corresponding value of **imgURL** for the column value and store it in a variable `$img`.

Then I have this functionality prepared to run the rest of my program:

```
$size = 100;
$lines = file_get_contents(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]), FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$words = explode(" ", $lines);
$words = array_splice($words, 0, count($words));
$img = Database entry

foreach ($words as $x => $word) {
    print '<div class="result" style="position: relative; float: left; 
            width:' . $size . 'px; margin: 5px; height:' . $size . 'px;  
          background-image:url('. $img .'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
            <a id="word' . $x . '">' . $words[$x] . '</a></div>';
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to put each word of an array into a separate `<div>` and then display it. All works well, I just need to show the corresponding img to the word as the background of the `<div>`

Anyone has any idea ? 
Any and all suggestions appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: So all the `<div>`s will have the same image? I ask because it looks like you just assign it just one time before the loop. What if you have one row with `BMW` and one row with `Volvo`, which image do you pick?

Comment: No the images have to  corespond to the words of course. But thats what I have a problem with.

Comment: In that case you should move your `$img = Database entry` line into your loop and run the query for each word. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it without database.**

1. Put all images to one directory(for example "**Words**")
2. Name all images corresponding to word they represent
   (for example **Volvo.png**,**BMW.png**)
3. Go thought array and set images paths

**Code sample**

```
for($x=0;$x<Count($x);$x++)
{
    echo'<div class="result" style="background-image:url("https://website.com/Words/'.$words[$x].'.png");background-size: 100% 100%;"><a id="word'. $x .'">'. $words[$x] .'</a></div>';
}
```

**Notes**

It is better solution, because don't need connect to database and will generate the page a bit faster.

Its downside is a space requirements to store all images.

Comment: Hi, that is an elegant solution ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the type of database you are using, I assume mysql. This code should suffice:

```
//                    IP            username       password    database
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'your_user', 'your_pass', 'sakila');
$sql = "select imUrl from  tableName where word = '".$cars[0]."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql));
$car_img = $result->fetch_assoc();
//access image using $car_img['imgUrl'];
```

Hope that helps. If you have multiple images you can through a loop around this and run it as often as you want, provided you store the `$car_img` somewhere so it is not overwritten.